# Link to the user's edit form of django admin from another page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

There's a different site with the currently logged in user's name on top. On clicking it, I need the edit form of that user from django-admin to be displayed. And not all should be displayed, for example, permissions block shouldn't be displayed, etc. How do I achieve this?

What I did:

**views.py**

```
def userprofile(request):
    return render(request, "userprofile.html", {'form': UserChangeForm})
```

In **userprofile.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table>
                {{form.as_table}}
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In **urls.py**

```
url(r'^admin/auth/user/(\d{1,2})/$', userprofile),
```

In **head.html** (the site where user profile link is at top right)

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;<a href = "/admin/auth/user/" title="Click Here to view user profile">User : {{user.username}} </a>
```

Where and how should the query be to get the *logged-in user's edit form??*
What is it like primary key of Model User in database, how to get this number?

[image]

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers This is what I've tried...

Comment: What's the point of "url(r'^admin/auth/user/(\d{1,2})/$', userprofile)" exactly ?

Comment: to get that number, here 64, how to get that number?

Comment: Getting the current logged in user from the request is fully explained in Django's FineManual(tm). And you did not answer my question above...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify `url(r'^admin/auth/user/(\d{1,2})/$', userprofile)` in `urlpatterns`. In templates you can use, for example, `{% url 'admin:auth_user_change' user.id %}`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).